# Calculate Satellite Coordinates From TLE Data

Tags: artificial-satellite, low-earth-orbit, ground-track

I know it is not that hard for those familiar with the equations for it, but I am having trouble with the math. In order to fully understand the orbit elements of TLEs I read [this](http://satelliteorbitdetermination.com/orbit_elements_wiki.htm) which I found very helpful, but I am struggling with turning that into latitude and longitude coordinates. I am coming into this with no knowledge of the necessary algorithms which is what I am hoping someone can point me to. [This](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2512/leo-metric-to-determine-the-ground-track-of-a-satellite) post provides some relevant information but if I understand correctly is only explaining how to get the longitude at a specific time while I would like the full coordinates.

Comment: Please put the full information from linked sites into your post to prevent link obsolescence ("rot"). What part of SGP/SDP algorithms does present difficulties for you?

Comment: The information in the first link would be hard to summarize here but I added a bit to the second one. I also elaborated on what I am asking for. I don't understand what equations/algorithms are used to determine a satellites position at a certain time based on its TLE data, and that's what I would like to know.

Comment: http://www.celestrak.com/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/ Please search for SGP4/SDP4 algorithms on the Web. Note: the above link leads to annotated source code (http://www.celestrak.com/publications/AIAA/2006-6753/AIAA-2006-6753.zip).

Comment: Could someone elaborate a little more about how to do it? @harry1795671: How did you use that Pyephem library?

Comment: @Qorzyking Please note we're not a discussion forum but a Q&A site. If you have a new question please [ask it as such](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Refer to our [About] and [Help] pages for more information how we function and organise things on [SE] that [space.se] is a part of. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/)
just like this

```
sudo apt-get install python

sudo apt-get install python-dev

sudo apt-get install python-pip

pip install pyephem
```

create test.py:

```
import ephem
import datetime
## [...]

name = "ISS (ZARYA)";
line1 = "1 25544U 98067A   12304.22916904  .00016548  00000-0  28330-3 0  5509";
line2 = "2 25544  51.6482 170.5822 0016684 224.8813 236.0409 15.51231918798998";

tle_rec = ephem.readtle(name, line1, line2);
tle_rec.compute();

print tle_rec.sublong, tle_rec.sublat;
```

Comment: Very nice! It's always good to see Python here. [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) is another Python package, and has a [tag here](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyfield) where some use examples can be found. It is based on different principles, but has some overlapping functionality. Both PyEphem and Skyfield are in fact managed by the [same person](http://space.stackexchange.com/users/8590/brandon-rhodes).

Comment: Now, I want to forecast orbit.what should I do?Just like this, input a  time, output a longitude and latitude. @uhoh Have you something idea?

Comment: Ya, the reason I didn't post another answer is that it does not appear to be so transparent to generate a *ground track* from an orbit in Skyfield. It's easy to get GCRS coordinates (x, y, z) or JD2000 coordinates, but if I understand correctly it's still up to the user to project down on to their own model for the Earth. Lat/lon are referenced to the Earth's surface, they are not necessarily precise space coordinates. If you ask this as another question here I can post short scripts for two different methods.

Comment: In the mean time, you can look at [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/19339/12102) and [Skyfield issue 121](https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/121).

Comment: Warning: pyephem is deprecated and no longer maintained (last release was in 2015). Skyfield however had most recent released February 2019 (4 months prior to this comment).

Answer (score 21):

There are a number of software packages, many of them free, that deal with those two line elements. **Use one of them.**

Those two line elements are not Keplerian elements. They are instead Brouwer-Lyddane mean orbital elements. Keplerian elements assume a spherical central body and no forces other than gravitation. The Brouwer-Lyddane mean orbital elements address the first six spherical harmonics and attempt to account for atmospheric drag. The mathematics of Keplerian elements is a bit messy. The mathematics of those two line elements is beyond messy. It's a "math-out". (Think of a blizzard where all you see is whiteness. Blizzards are white-out conditions. The paper describing the two line elements is a math-out. All you see is mathematics.)

The mathematics is described in [F.R. Hoots, "Reformulation of the Brouwer geopotential theory for improved computational efficiency", *Celestial Mechanics* 24 (1981)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1981CeMec..24..367H).

Comment: In the end I settled on using Pyephem, a python library capable of doing the calculations fairly easily.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which algorithm/set of equations you are using to convert, you may need to convert the TLE parameters into ECEF coordinates, then convert that into latitude, longitude, and altitude.  Here is a page that explains the ECEF-to-LLA conversion: 
http://www.gmat.unsw.edu.au/snap/gps/clynch_pdfs/coordcvt.pdf

A common math difficulty is that the true anomaly and the mean anomaly are related by Kepler's equation, which is a transcendental equation as your first link mentioned.  An iterative method like Newton's Method is usually used for this part of the conversion.

I can't seem to find a webpage that has the set of algorithms for converting TLE to ECEF, but this page gives the algorithm for converting GPS ephemerides (orbital parameters) into ECEF coordinates: http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~ecalais/teaching/geodesy/EAS_591T_2003_lab_4.htm
If I remember correctly the TLE conversion is pretty similar, so that might get you on the right track.  If you don't have a textbook with the algorithm, it might be online in a paper or something.

Comment: Please expand and include the relevant math for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

Comment: Note: the first link is now dead.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similair question, and using pyephem as suggested by zdRan worked great, except for one thing:  Those are instructions for Debian/Ubuntu/etc. distributions and I was on a bare-bones CentOS install.

In case anyone else runs into this, here's the install instructions, to be used in place of the first block in zdRan's post:

```
sudo yum install python
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum upgrade python-setuptools
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install python-pip
sudo yum install gcc
sudo pip install pyephem
```

The `epel-release` is needed since pip isn't part of the core pacakges for CentOS, but is part of the extended packages.  `gcc` only needs to be installed if you don't already have it (you can use `whereis gcc` to check, but yum won't install if already there, so not strictly necessary).

From there, proceed as above, works great.

(This was on CentOS 7, but a similair procedure should work for most CentOS/Red Hat/Fedora distributions)