# How to find coordinates based on TLE information?

Tags: artificial-satellite

For a school project I have to find coordinates using the TLE information. Does anyone know how to do this or know a program that can do this?

Thanks in advance

P.S. I know there is a question just like this on here but it is not very clear to me yet.

Comment: Use pyephem.  It implements SGP4 and is straightforward to use.

Comment: Frankly, when I [suggested](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/calculate-satellite-coordinates-from-tle-data/5524#comment15012_4211) you ask a new question after posting request for clarification in a new answer (since deleted as _not an answer_) to the thread that this one is marked as a duplicate of, I expected you'd clarify what specifically you don't understand about it, not merely vaguely rewrite an already asked question. Please see if you could [edit] to clarify your question and make it specific enough to be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a piece of software called SGP4 (Simple General Perturbations algorithm 4).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models

Given a TLE (Two Line Element) this software will give you the ECI (Earth Centered Inertial) position and velocity coordinates of the object as a function of time.

There are alot of different implementations out there but you need to have some programming expertise to use them directly.