# ISS (ZARYA) TLE to Latitude Longitude Conversion

Tags: orbital-mechanics, iss, frames

I am trying to take TLE of ISS (ZARYA) and get the latitude longitude and height. I am aware the TLE is in TEME~(True Equator Mean Equinox) frame. This means that the TLE was generated considering the True Equator as of TLE generation time and X axis pointing to mean equinox. Thus, if I were to calculate instantaneous latitude, longitude and altitude at the TLE generation point I need not worry about the precession and nutation complexity. I am also aware that LLH of ISS is expressed in geodetic coordinates. Now getting the exact sidereal time at the TLE generation time seems to be a little involved process involving UT1 and GMST equations (and UTC!), but I am able to bypass that problem by considering a UT1 time and sidereal time at 1 Jan 2023 12:00PM and then assume them to linearly related for short time. I am assuming within an year deviation will be small enough.

Anyway, I am first trying to attack the latitude problem, which is indepedent of sidereal angle and must come very close to actual number.

I am considering this TLE. Which is for date `2023-05-25 07:49:28.500`
I derived the date using [tle to date](http://mason.gmu.edu/%7Emlyons3/tle_epoch.html) online utility

```
ISS (ZARYA)             
1 25544U 98067A   23145.32602431  .00014206  00000+0  25493-3 0  9994
2 25544  51.6413  81.8570 0005396  18.1967 120.0030 15.50160974398246
```

Now using historical ISS data I am able to pull the latitude longitude and height
at this time [ISS Hitorical Data](http://www.isstracker.com/historical)

```
Lat: 31.581 deg
Lon: -127.093 deg
Ht : 419.88 km
```

The inertial vectors I derived using the mathematical equations as defined in [kep2cart](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810015111/http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5070/handouts/kep2cart_2002.doc) doc are

```
-3498.170819 -4621.733107  3548.392785     2.785672    -5.551759    -4.477993
```

Now using [this ECEF to LLH](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760012748/downloads/19760012748.pdf) online utility I can convert to geodetic lat lon ht:

```
Latitude  : 31.63493   deg N
Longitude : 232.87807   deg E (forget this for a while)
Height    : 423939.5   m
```

The two latitudes are off by 0.05 degrees. Why there is this difference? Or I am assuming something about precession and nutation that I cannot?

Another issue is the altitude, using WGS84 system altitude should also come exact. Why is there difference in altitude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is TLEs [do not mean what you think they mean](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37042/mean-to-osculating-conversion-for-non-j2-averaged-elements/57456#57456), so you [can't use them that way](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63245/teme-state-vector-to-tle-orbital-elements/63250#63250).  The equations in the kep2cart doc you linked are simply wrong when applied to TLEs.  If you want to successfully convert a TLE to inertial vectors or LLH, you [must use SGP4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57276/failing-at-getting-apogee-and-perigee-from-tle/57335#57335), which exists solely for that purpose, and does [far more math](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/43283/confused-about-sgp4-implementation-published-by-celestrack/56096#56096) than you can possibly hope to code successfully on your own.  Nothing about TLEs is exact, because they describe the ***average*** state, not the instantaneous one.  Errors of several kilometers and several meters per second are routine ***at epoch***, and grow quadratically from there.  Finally, the TLE model is so old that they actually use WGS72, not WGS84.

Comment: Ah! seems like a well trodden road of failed attempts. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure.  It seems my lot in life to answer this question. :)